# PHP Data Submision Error

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a very basic self calling form and I seem to have an error that I can't deal with..
This is the part of the page I have issues with:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="container 75%">
<div class="row uniform 50%">
<div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
<input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
<input name="pass" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" class="special" value="Submit" /></li>
<li><input type="reset" class="alt" value="Reset" /></li>
</ul>
</form>

</div>
</section>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//....
}
?>
```

The `$_POST['submit']` value is undefined even if I press the submit button.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the `name` attribute to the submit button. Otherwise it can't be accessed using `$_POST` array.

```
<input type="submit" name = "submit" class="special" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, a variable or array element which has never been set is different from one whose value is null; attempting to access an unset value is a run time error.

You should add `name="submit"` because in `$_POST` it work like index of array which use for printing value.

```
<li><input type="submit" class="special" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
```